# how to prevent an array of colors from being the same random array every time the arduino starts

Tags: c++, arrays, random, arduino, random-seed

I have an array which stores some uint32_t neopxiel colors: red, green, blue, and yellow:

```
uint32_t colorRed = pixels.Color(255, 0, 0);
uint32_t colorGreen = pixels.Color(0, 150, 0);
uint32_t colorBlue = pixels.Color(0, 255, 255);
uint32_t colorYellow = pixels.Color(255, 255, 0);

uint32_t colorArray[4] = {colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue, colorYellow};
```

Then I want to make an array that holds these colors in random order every time the arduino starts up.

```
uint32_t patternArray[4] = {colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)]};
```

This seems to have made a random order of those 4 colors, but it is the same "random" order every time the arduino starts up (yellow, green, green, blue).

How do I make that random order different every time the arduino starts up?

I've tried declaring a placeholder array and initializing it after the randomSeed(0) thing that most forum posts suggest, but I can't seem to get the right syntax for declaring the array and then later assigning values to it:

```
//uint32_t patternArray; //nope
//uint32_t patternArray[4]; //nope


setup(){
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  //patternArray = {colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)]}; //nope
  patternArray[4] = {colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)], colorArray[random(4)]}; //nope

}
```

Comment: Try `randomSeed(millis());` instead.  It could be that pin `0` is always the same value which means the seed would always be the same which means the sequence will b the same.

Comment: Thanks - I thought about this - it still returns the same pattern. I think part of the problem might be that I'm declaring the patternArray before setup calls the randomSeed - but I don't know how to make a placeholder array and then push values to it without errors.

Comment: Oh, do'h.  You can't assign arrays like that in C++.  You'd need `patternArray[0] = colorArray[random(4)]; patternArray[1] =  colorArray[random(4)]; patternArray[2] =  colorArray[random(4)]; patternArray[3] = colorArray[random(4)];` (or use a loop)

Comment: Dang - that worked in terms of instantiating the color array after the randomSeed, but it still generates the same color pattern every time (yellow,green,green,blue)

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - I figured it out based on your comment. If you post it as an answer (minus the randomSeed(millis()) part, that didn't work), I'll accept it.

Comment: Since you already have an answer for that on your other question you can just accept that.

Comment: Well, I knew about the random seed bit (even included it in my original question). What I was doing wrong was trying to assign the random colors in an improper manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that finally worked was similar to what  @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica suggested. I was assigning array values in the wrong way. Also, the `randomSeed(millis())` in didn't work, but the `randomSeed(analogRead(1))` did, however, the `random()` call cannot be in the setup method - it has to be in the loop.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  randomSeed(analogRead(1));
}

void loop(){
  for (int i=-0; i<totalPatternLength;i++){
    int randIndex = random(totalNumColors);
    patternArray[i] = colorArray[randIndex];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`analogRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/)

> Reads the value from the specified analog pin. Arduino boards contain a multichannel, 10-bit analog to digital converter. This means that it will map input voltages between 0 and the operating voltage(5V or 3.3V) into integer values between 0 and 1023.

So whatever voltage level is at pin 0, it is always the same, and therefore the seed for random is always the same.

---

Using time as a seed value ensures having a different value each time the program is started, e.g. [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/)

> Returns the number of milliseconds passed since the Arduino board began running the current program. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days.

---

Alternatively, look at the example at [`randomSeed()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/randomseed/)

> **Example Code**
>   The code generates a pseudo-random number and sends the generated number to the serial port.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}
```

which is almost what you have. Maybe doing `Serial.begin()` is the needed trick.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf Dietsche - any idea how to create an array of colors that is different every time?

Comment: Yes - I've added Serial.begin before analogRead and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @mheavers Then, I'm out of ideas, sorry.